# Ramda: How can I make this imperative reducer more declarative?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have the following reducer function:

The *first* argument to the reducers is the aggregated value, and the *second* argument is the next value. The below reducer function is reducing over the same `reaction` argument but aggregating the `state$` value. Each reducer function yields a new aggregated value.

```js
/**
 * Applies all the reducers to create a state object.
 */
function reactionReducer(reaction: ReactionObject): ReactionObject {
    let state$ = reactionDescriptionReducer({}, reaction);
    state$ = reactionDisabledReducer(state$, reaction);
    state$ = reactionIconReducer(state$, reaction);
    state$ = reactionOrderReducer(state$, reaction);
    state$ = reactionStyleReducer(state$, reaction);
    state$ = reactionTitleReducer(state$, reaction);
    state$ = reactionTooltipReducer(state$, reaction);
    state$ = reactionVisibleReducer(state$, reaction);
    return state$;
}

const state = reactionReducer(value);
```

The above works but the function is *fixed* with the list of reducers. It seems like I should be able to do something like this with RamdaJS.

```js
const state = R.????({}, value, [reactionDescriptionReducer
    reactionDisabledReducer,
    reactionIconReducer,
    reactionOrderReducer,
    reactionStyleReducer,
    reactionTitleReducer,
    reactionTooltipReducer,
    reactionVisibleReducer]);
```

I am new to RamdaJS so forgive me if this is a noob question.

How can I execute a chain of reducers using just RamdaJS?

Comment: Did you try using [`ap`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#ap), to create a list of functions?

Comment: Review `curry`, `flip`, `juxt`, `map`, and `pipe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option of utilising Ramda here would be to make use of the fact that it supports passing functions as a monad instance to [`R.chain`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) (otherwise known as the Reader monad).

This lets you sequence a number of functions together that share some common environment - in your case, `reaction`.

We can make use of [`R.pipeWith(R.chain)`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipeWith) to allow composing a series of these functions that take some input (e.g. your `$state` threading through each function) and returns a function that takes the environment, producing a result to pass on to the next function in the pipeline.

```js
// Some mock functions to demonstrate

const reactionDescriptionReducer = ({...state}, reaction) =>
  ({ description: reaction, ...state })

const reactionDisabledReducer = ({...state}, reaction) =>
  ({ disabled: reaction, ...state })

const reactionIconReducer = ({...state}, reaction) =>
  ({ icon: reaction, ...state })

// effectively `R.pipeK`
const kleisli = R.pipeWith(R.chain)

// we need the functions going into chain to be curried
const curried = f => a => b => f(a, b)

// finally, compose the series of functions together
const reactReducer = kleisli([
  curried(reactionDescriptionReducer),
  curried(reactionDisabledReducer),
  curried(reactionIconReducer)
])({})

// and if all goes well...
console.log(
  reactReducer("someCommonReactionValue")
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know `R.chain` supported functions in this way. Small spelling correction: `kleisli`

Comment: You never know, one day we might get `Function.prototype.flatMap` :D

Answer (score 4):

`and` constructs a new reducer, `(r, x) => ...`, by combining the two (2) input reducers, `f` and `g` -

```
const and = (f, g) =>
  (r, x) => g (f (r, x), x)
```

`all`, by use of `and`, constructs a new reducer by combining an arbitrary number of reducers -

```
const identity = x =>
  x

const all = (f = identity, ...more) =>
  more .reduce (and, f)
```

Define `myReducer` using `all` -

```
const myReducer =
  all
    ( reactionDisabledReducer
    , reactionIconReducer
    , reactionOrderReducer
    // ...
    )
```

Given a mocked implementation for these three (3) reducers -

```
const reactionDisabledReducer = (s, x) =>
  x < 0
    ? { ...s, disabled: true }
    : s

const reactionIconReducer = (s, x) =>
  ({ ...s, icon: `${x}.png` })

const reactionOrderReducer = (s, x) =>
  x > 10
    ? { ...s, error: "over 10" }
    : s
```

Run `myReducer` to see the outputs

```
const initState =
  { foo: "bar" }

myReducer (initState, 10)
// { foo: 'bar', icon: '10.png' }

myReducer (initState, -1)
// { foo: 'bar', disabled: true, icon: '-1.png' }

myReducer (initState, 100)
// { foo: 'bar', icon: '100.png', error: 'over 10' }
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your browser -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const and = (f, g) =>
  (r, x) => g (f (r, x), x)

const all = (f, ...more) =>
  more .reduce (and, f)

const reactionDisabledReducer = (s, x) =>
  x < 0
    ? { ...s, disabled: true }
    : s

const reactionIconReducer = (s, x) =>
  ({ ...s, icon: `${x}.png` })

const reactionOrderReducer = (s, x) =>
  x > 10
    ? { ...s, error: "over 10" }
    : s

const myReducer =
  all
    ( reactionDisabledReducer
    , reactionIconReducer
    , reactionOrderReducer
    // ...
    )

const initState =
  { foo: "bar" }

console .log (myReducer (initState, 10))
// { foo: 'bar', icon: '10.png' }

console .log (myReducer (initState, -1))
// { foo: 'bar', disabled: true, icon: '-1.png' }

console .log (myReducer (initState, 100))
// { foo: 'bar', icon: '100.png', error: 'over 10' }
```

---

You can choose whatever names you like for `and` and `all`. I could see them as part of a `reducer` module, like `reducer.and` and `reducer.all`

Answer (score 3):

My first attempt would not involve Ramda at all, just a simple:

```js
const makeReducer = (...fns) => (x) => fns .reduce ( (s, fn) => fn (s, x), {} )

const fn = makeReducer (
  (state$, reaction) => ({...state$, foo: `<<-${reaction.foo}->>`}),
  (state$, reaction) => ({...state$, bar: `=*=${reaction.bar}=*=`}),
  (state$, reaction) => ({...state$, baz: `-=-${reaction.baz}-=-`})
)

console .log (
  fn ( {foo: 'a', bar: 'b', baz: 'c'} )
) //~> {foo: '<<-a->>', bar: '=*=b=*=', baz: '-=-c-=-'}
```

While you could choose to use Ramda's [`reduce`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduce) and [`flip`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#flip), it doesn't seem as though they'll add much here.